# Is there a reserved thread-id value?

Tags: winapi

When I call GetCurrentThreadId, is there a reserved value that will never be used for a thread-id, maybe zero ? I want to get the thread-id directly from the TIB and I need a reserved value. Otherwise I'd use a additional bool.

Comment: "*I want to get the thread-id directly from the TIB and I need a reserved value*" - Why?  If you are accessing a thread's TIB, then obviously the thread is alive and so by definition it must have a valid ID, so there is no need to compare it to anything.  Either you are able to get the ID, or you are not.  There is no in-between.  "*Otherwise I'd use a additional bool*" - for what purpose?  What is your actual goal with this? This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: XY Problem: that I'm accessing the TIB has nothing to do that I need a null thread-id.

Comment: "*I need a null thread-id*" - but WHY?  What are you going to do with it? The XY portion of this question is that you are focusing on the null itself, rather than on the reason why you need the null in the first place

Comment: I've got a thread_id-class that has a state which represents no thread. And this state is needed for comparison. It's not your issue why I need this.

Comment: Saying that you are getting the thread id from the TIB is not relevant to the question and served only to create confusion, since a thread id obtained from the TIB is never null. (Also, why not just call GetCurrentThreadId?)

Answer (score 4):

Thread ID of a valid thread is always non-zero. See [Thread Handles and Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-handles-and-identifiers) which states:

> Note that no thread identifier will ever be 0.